# How to Run Python (with imported modules) from Applescript => Module Not Found Errors

Tags: python-3.x, applescript

How do I run a python script (with imported modules) from Applescript?

From terminal, these scripts work fine

```
python -m api.get_classrooms

python /absolute/path/to/project/api/get_classrooms.py
```

If I run the terminal script from AppleScript, I get module not found errors:

```
set pythonPath to "/path/to/anaconda3/envs/jupyter/bin/python"
set scriptPath to "/absolute/path/to/project/api/get_classrooms.py"
set result to do shell script pythonPath & " " & scriptPath & " "
```

I get the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api'"
```

I did add my project to the $PYTHONPATH within .bash_profile

```
echo $PYTHONPATH => /path/to/project/a
```

And the python file (called by AppleScript) is set to executable

Is Applescript not aware of the PYTHONPATH?

Any push in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [ted wrigley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11722376/ted-wrigley) :) I was finally able to get it to work...
By **not** targeting the get_classrooms.py script directly.
Instead, AppleScript runs the below shell script (working within the project's subdirectory 'bash'. 
The bash script executes the python script. 
It wasn't the exact solution I wanted...but it works...and is (perhaps) more elegant....at least until the project is converted to a webapp with flask.

For anyone having trouble targeting python scripts with applescript
 **applescript=>bash=>python**

Applescript

```
do shell script "/Users/me/path/to/project/bash/applescript.sh"
```

Bash script within project/bash directory

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# eval /usr/libexec/path_helper -s; # didn't need
export PYTHONPATH='/Users/me/path/to/project';
/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/jupyter/bin/python -m api.get_classrooms
```

Comment: As mentioned, you shouldn't rely on a specific environment when using `do shell script`, as it does not read the configuration files that an interactive shell running in Terminal would.  If a particular environment is needed, you need to set it up in the shell.

Comment: @red_menace Can you expand on how to properly set up the environment in the shell for this purpose? If I'm using `zsh` am I supposed to put something in `.zshrc`? Or run a Shell Script in Automator before I call the AppleScript? I want to do this correctly so the Service doesn't import the modules on every run.

Comment: Each `do shell script` is a new environment, so you would need to set it up each time and perform everything in that statement.  You could use something like `source` to reload your zsh settings.

Answer (score 0):

AppleScript's `do shell script` does not import the environment used by a typical interactive shell. This includes the $PATH variable, which I suspect is where your pro blew lies.  You can coerce it into doing a full setup by calling the path_helper utility that apps like Terminal use.  Try running this code:

```
set pythonPath to "/path/to/anaconda3/envs/jupyter/bin/python"
set scriptPath to "/absolute/path/to/project/api/get_classrooms.py"
set result to do shell script "eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`; python -m api.get_classrooms"
```

Comment: I still got the module-not-found error with your script above. The only thing that worked was moving the script to the root directory of the project...not within the project's api directory. Do you know what would cause this? Thank you :)

Comment: I am not really proficient with python (at least, not like I am with AppleScript) so I don't have a good idea.  but I'll look into it further.

Comment: @grahama: Out of curiosity, what output do you get when you run `echo $PYTHONPATH` in terminal?

Comment: With echo $PYTHONPATH, I get the proper path => /Users/me/path/to/project/dir. That said, I am running a conda virtual environment for this project. Within the terminal script,  I'll try running 'source activate my_environment' before I executing the python script. Perhaps that will work....

Comment: Yeah, I think that is the problem: `$PYTHONPATH` is not set when you use `do shell script`. Keep in mind, though, that each `do shell script` is a different shell instance. You either have to chain your commands into one dss, or activate the environment each time you use dss.

Comment: Apparently, adding the venv doesn't work either....works in terminal but not within applescript...must be something else :\
set condaPath to "/Users/me/anaconda3/bin/activate"
set venvPath to "/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/venv"
set condaCmd to condaPath & " " & venvPath & ";"
set pythonPath to "/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/venv/bin/python"
set scriptPath to "/Users/me/path/to/project/api/get_classrooms.py"

set result to do shell script condaCmd & " " & pythonPath & " " & scriptPath
result

Comment: Well, you could try just setting the variable: e.g. `do shell script "eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`; export PYTHONPATH='/Users/me/path/to/project/dir'; python -m api.get_classrooms"`